# Solving AX=B when some elements of both X and B are unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an issue and I've tried googling but nothing came up.
There is a matrix equation:

$AX=B$

If there are unknown elements in both X and B, such that a known in X corresponds to an unknown in B and vice versa, is there a way to solve this system as a matrix?
I'm sorry if this is very basic but I don't know how to do this

Comment: Try a stochastic analysis through possible values for entries of $B$ and solve for $X$.

Comment: I thought all coefficients of $X$ are unknown in $AX=B$, i.e, we are solving for $X$?

Comment: Can't you rearrange this to give a standard system of linear equations?  In each equation, bring the unknowns to the left-hand side and the constants to the right-hand side?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you have something like $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}x\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\y\end{pmatrix}$$
In this particular case $AX=B$ yields $x=1=1$. But it's not always solvable. Choose for example $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $$AX=\begin{pmatrix}1\\x\end{pmatrix}$$
So this will yield $x=y$, for any $x$. If you choose $$B=\begin{pmatrix}2\\y\end{pmatrix}$$ then $AX=B$ will become
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\y\end{pmatrix}$$
This does not have a solution